# Aurelia Dynamic Routes From REST API

Tags: javascript, routes, aurelia

I'm in a tricky position. I'm working on an Aurelia app that has some routes that gets set based off of a simple GET request to an API.

What works (no API request, or delay in `configureRouter` step):

```js
export class MyClass{
  static inject = [some stuff here];

  configureRouter(config, router) {
    this.router = router;

    let routes = [
{ route: '', redirect: 'landing' },
{ route: 'landing', name: 'landing', moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('components/landing'), title: 'landing' },
{ route: 'pageA', name: 'pageA', moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('components/pageA'), title: 'Page A' },
{ route: 'pageB', name: 'pageB', moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('components/pageB'), title: 'Page B' }];

config.map(routes);
  }
```

What doesn't work:

```js
export class MyClass{
  static inject = [some stuff here];

  configureRouter(config, router) {
    this.router = router;

    let routes = [
{ route: '', redirect: 'landing' },
{ route: 'landing', name: 'landing', moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('components/landing'), title: 'landing' }];

this.routesRepo.get().then((data) => {
// data is array representing
// [{ route: 'pageA', name: 'pageA', moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('components/pageA'), title: 'Page A' },
//  { route: 'pageB', name: 'pageB', moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('components/pageB'), title: 'Page B' }];

routes.concat(data);
config.map(routes);
  }
});
```

Also what doesn't work (simple timeout):

```js
export class MyClass{
  static inject = [some stuff here];

  configureRouter(config, router) {
    this.router = router;

    let routes = [];

    setTimeOut(() => {
     routes.concat(
[ { route: '', redirect: 'landing' },
  { route: 'landing', name: 'landing', moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('components/landing'), title: 'landing' },
  { route: 'pageA', name: 'pageA', moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('components/pageA'), title: 'Page A' },
  { route: 'pageB', name: 'pageB', moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('components/pageB'), title: 'Page B' } ]);

      config.map(routes);
    }, 1);
  }
```

Why does adding `config.map(routes)` within the promise mess everything up? How does one go about this then? The `routes` array has everything it needs and is set up properly before it reaches `config.map(routes)`. All I get now is my custom 404 page.

Thanks!

Comment: I guess the issue is that in the 2nd and 3rd example, configureRouter is returning before the call to config.map completes. This is because in the 2nd there is a Promise and in the 3rd case a timeout in the process queue. My best guess is that you should return a Promise expecting the call to the api to fulfill. This way, the framework "knows" there is an impending promise. Good luck,

Comment: try returning the promise from `configureRouter`.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks @CristiánOrmazábal.